# How can I embed IPython notebooks and their outputs in a larger IPython notebook?

Tags: python, algorithm, report, ipython, jupyter-notebook

My goal is to evaluate and compare various algorithms. I would like the outputs and results of each algorithm collected in one, easy-to-read file. I am picking IPython notebooks because I want:

- Printed results to be next to code
- Graphs and figures to be inline with code
- Text, formulas, and equations to be formatted correctly

I plan on each algorithm being its own notebook. I would like a single notebook to round up all potential algorithms and run them sequentially.

The source and results of each algorithm should be inline / embedded in the "main" notebook. Finally, the "main" notebook would be converted to PDF for view by people.

Is this possible with IPython? Is there perhaps a more sane way to go about this?